# How to get virtual key codes from KeyPress and KeyRelease events in X11 with modifier keys down

Tags: c, x11, xlib

When receiving a `KeyPress` or `KeyRelease` event from X11, how can I translate the result into a virtual code that maps to the physical keys 0 to 9 and A to Z, independent of the keyboard layout and independent of any modifier keys being down?

I've tried this:

```
XLookupString((XKeyEvent *) &ev, buffer, 10, &keysym, &compose);
```

This gives me a `keysym` but this is not what I want because it changes as soon as one of the modifier keys like SHIFT, ALT, etc. is pressed. For example, when pressing "1" on a German keyboard with SHIFT, `keysym` will be 33 which corresponds to the `!` character. I want to have the information that "1" has been pressed, however.

I've also tried to look at the `keycode` member of `XKeyEvent` but this is also not helpful because it seems to be a raw scancode which is not of help here because it will map to different keys in different languages.

So how can I find out the key that has been pressed even if modifier keys like SHIFT, ALT, etc. are also down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question: `XKeycodeToKeysym()` with the `index` parameter set to 0 allows me to get the raw key without any modifier modification from the `XKeyEvent`.